# Failed when posting with Ionic/Angular using POST method

Tags: angular, ionic3, rxjs6

This problem just happened and began to happen like this, out of nowhere, apparently for no reason at all. It simply does not complete the request from the POST method call to webservice.

I honestly can not see any problems in the code, even though it was working normally just now.

The worst thing is that in the Chrome console does not show any error, only points that failed:

```
polyfills.js:3 
XHR failed loading: OPTIONS "http://MY-SERVER:5000/profiles/set-logged-profile".

s @ polyfills.js:3
t.scheduleTask @ polyfills.js:3
onScheduleTask @ polyfills.js:3
t.scheduleTask @ polyfills.js:3
r.scheduleTask @ polyfills.js:3
r.scheduleMacroTask @ polyfills.js:3
(anonymous) @ polyfills.js:3
o.(anonymous function) @ polyfills.js:2
(anonymous) @ http.js:1630
Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:43
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:29
(anonymous) @ subscribeTo.js:21
subscribeToResult @ subscribeToResult.js:11
MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub @ mergeMap.js:74
MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext @ mergeMap.js:68
MergeMapSubscriber._next @ mergeMap.js:51
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:54
(anonymous) @ scalar.js:5
Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:43
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:29
MergeMapOperator.call @ mergeMap.js:29
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:24
FilterOperator.call @ filter.js:15
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:24
MapOperator.call @ map.js:18
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:24
TakeUntilOperator.call @ takeUntil.js:17
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:24
webpackJsonp.620.HomePage.ionViewWillEnter @ home.ts:134
ViewController._lifecycle @ view-controller.js:486
ViewController._willEnter @ view-controller.js:384
NavControllerBase._willEnter @ nav-controller-base.js:780
(anonymous) @ nav-controller-base.js:673
t.invoke @ polyfills.js:3
onInvoke @ core.js:14191
t.invoke @ polyfills.js:3
r.run @ polyfills.js:3
NgZone.run @ core.js:14105
NavControllerBase._viewsWillLifecycles @ nav-controller-base.js:667
Animation._fireBeforeReadFunc @ animation.js:723
Animation._beforeAnimation @ animation.js:652
Animation._playDomInspect @ animation.js:346
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Platform.raf @ platform.js:538
(anonymous) @ animation.js:292
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Platform.raf @ platform.js:538
Animation.play @ animation.js:291
NavControllerBase._transitionStart @ nav-controller-base.js:605
(anonymous) @ nav-controller-base.js:533
t.invoke @ polyfills.js:3
onInvoke @ core.js:14191
t.invoke @ polyfills.js:3
r.run @ polyfills.js:3
(anonymous) @ polyfills.js:3
t.invokeTask @ polyfills.js:3
onInvokeTask @ core.js:14182
t.invokeTask @ polyfills.js:3
r.runTask @ polyfills.js:3
o @ polyfills.js:3
Promise.then (async)
r @ polyfills.js:3
t.scheduleTask @ polyfills.js:3
onScheduleTask @ polyfills.js:3
t.scheduleTask @ polyfills.js:3
r.scheduleTask @ polyfills.js:3
r.scheduleMicroTask @ polyfills.js:3
f @ polyfills.js:3
c @ polyfills.js:3
(anonymous) @ polyfills.js:3
Animation._didFinish @ animation.js:994
Animation._didFinishAll @ animation.js:981
onTransitionEnd @ animation.js:428
onTransitionEnd @ platform.js:610
```

I'm using RxJs 6+ with Angular 7+, below the code of my "service" that makes the POST request:

```
  public sendPost(url: string, payload: any, showLoading: boolean = true) {
    if (this.isConnected) {
      this.loadingStatus(showLoading);
      let endPoint: string = this.setEndPoint(url);
      let headers: any = this.requestHeaders();
      console.log('ENDPOINT: ' + endPoint);
      let observable$: Observable < any > = this.http.post(endPoint, payload, headers);
      observable$.pipe(
        retryWhen(genericRetryStrategy()),
        tap(() => {
          console.log("HTTP POST request executed and finished");
          this.loadingStatus(false);
        }),
        catchError(err => {
          this.loadingStatus(false);
          return throwError(err);
        }));
      return observable$;
    } else {
      return this.error$;
    }
  }
```

Did anybody face a situation like this before?

Comment: The fact that the error message mentions an OPTIONS request suggests that you're having a CORS problem. You'll need to either set up the webpack dev server proxy, or configure your back-end to allow a cross-origin request.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

When subscribing I have a "takeUntil" and I was setting the wrong value to the destroyer observable:

```
this.destroy$.next(false); // changed to false
this.destroy$.complete(); // and added this

this.profileService.setLoginProfile(profieData, false)
  .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
  .subscribe((profile) => {
    this.help.preferences.profile = profile;

    this.help.tabEnabled = true;

    this.destroy$.next(true);

  }, error => {
    this.help.showToast(error.message);
  });
```